# Operator defined on periodic-distribution sobolev space

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, fourier-transform

Let $T = \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ be the one dimensional-torus, and $$A:H^2(T)\to L^2(T)\;\;\\A u = iu_{xx}$$
I want to know if this operator is closed, and i'm having issues and not knowing how to start since i don't really know how to start working on Torus. For the record, if $u \in D'(T)$ we define $||.||_{H^2(t)}$ by $$||u||^2_{H^2(t)} =  \displaystyle\sum_{\xi \in \mathbb{Z}} \langle\xi\rangle^4 |\widehat{u}(\xi)|^2$$ where $\widehat{u}$ is the laplace transform and $\langle\xi\rangle = (1+||\xi||^2)^{1/2}$.

Thank you in advance

Comment: The operator is unbounded, so by closed you mean that its graph is closed, right? That is, if $u_n \to u$, and $A(u_n) \to y$, then $y = A(u)$.

Comment: Ya, that's what o mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $u_n\to u$ and $(A u_n)\to v$ in $L^2(T)$. By Parseval's identity, $\hat u_n\to \hat u$ and $\widehat{A u_n}(\xi)=-i\lvert\xi\rvert^2\hat u_n(\xi)\to \hat v$ in $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$. In particular, both sequences are bounded.

It follows from the Fatou's lemma that
$$
\sum_{\xi\in\mathbb{Z}}\langle\xi\rangle^4\lvert \hat u(\xi)\rvert^2\leq\liminf_{n\to\infty}\sum_{\xi\in \mathbb{Z}}\langle \xi\rangle^4\lvert\hat u_n(\xi)\rvert^2\leq 2\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \sum_{\xi\in\mathbb{Z}}(1+\lvert \xi\rvert^4)\lvert \hat u_n(\xi)\rvert^2<\infty.
$$
Thus $u\in H^2(T)$. A very simlar application of Fatou's lemma also shows $\widehat{A u_n}\to \widehat{A u}$ in $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$, that is, $Au_n\to A u$ in $L^2(T)$.

A slightly more elegant way to see that $A$ is closed would be to show that multiplication by $-i\lvert \cdot\rvert^2$ with the natural domain is skew self-adjoint on $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ - this follows more or less from the definition - and then to use that adjoints of operators are always closed.

Comment: Hope u reply back, i came back to this post, and now, i dont see how come we can use dominated convergence theorem, i know that we can dominate $\lvert\hat u_n(\xi)\rvert^2$ since $\hat u_n(\xi)$ belong to Schwarz space, but which function dominate $\lvert \xi\rvert^4\lvert\hat u_n(\xi)\rvert^2$ ?

Comment: @AlekMurt, You're right, I was not careful. One should use Fatou's lemma instead (see the edit).

Comment: Thank you for repyling back.

Comment: hey man coming back, i really can't remember my thoughts on why u changed the $lim inf$ to $sup$, could u please tell me why did u do that? Sorry for very late reply. Thank you in advance

Comment: It is enough to know that the left-hand side is finite, so you may as well bound everything on the right-hand side by the supremum. You could calculate the limit instead of the supremum, but that just gives you more information than you need at this stage, so why bother?